# php include not working

Tags: php, include

I’ve got a PHP file with a switch case to include different files depending on a variable `$view`.

This was working perfectly when I was running this on WAMP server on my local machine.
But now I have uploaded to a web server and the `include` functions have just stopped working. Nothing is getting included.

```
switch($view)
    {
    case 'AddToCart':
        echo 'adding to cart';
        if($_POST['qty']>0)
        {
            if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]))
            {
                $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]=$_POST['qty'];
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]+= $_POST['qty'];
            }   
        }
        header('Location:index.php');
        break;

    case 'UpdateCart':
        echo 'updating cart...';
        if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]))
        {
            if($_POST['updateqty']>0)
                $_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]=$_POST['updateqty'];
            else
                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]);
        }   
        header('Location:index.php?view=ViewCart');
        break;

    case 'ViewCart':
        echo 'This is the full feature cart.';
        include('models\cart.php');
        include('models\fullcart.php');
        break;

    case 'Checkout':
        echo 'reached checkout';
        include('models\finalcart.php');

        break;

    case 'ClearCart':
        echo 'Clear cart reached';
        $_SESSION['cart']=array();
        $_SESSION['total_items']=0;
        $_SESSION['total_price']=0;
        header('Location:index.php');
        break;

    case 'RemoveItem':
        echo 'Removing item '.$_POST['id'].'<br><br>';
        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['id']]);
        header('Location:index.php?view=ViewCart');
        break;

    default:
        echo 'index page...lalalalalal...<br>';
        include('models\cart.php');
        include('models\catalog.php');
    }
```

I did `phpinfo` on the webserver and found it’s running PHP version 5.2.17.

Whats going wrong?

Comment: Are the files there in the correct paths? Do they have the correct permissions? Do you get any error/warning messages?

Comment: Off the top of my head, this could be a directory separator issue since Window uses \ and Unix /. However, have you got your error reporting turned on?

Answer (score 3):

Hope you know not to echo/print anything before you send headers. 
And can you check what your server os is, I use /, not \, in file paths

Comment: yes that was it the slashes... many thanks good sir... my stupidity, the slashes are the first thing i should have checked but it never occurred to me that there may be a problem with the slashes...

Answer (score 2):

I guess your web server is running linux or another unix-like system, which uses forward slashes instead of backslashes as directory seperator. So you have to replace the slashes in the include paths:

```
include('models\fullcart.php');
```

becomes

```
include('models/fullcart.php');
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

check the included file permissions i think they should be 755 or 775